How to add a List into another List type attribute in a class
I'm trying to make a console app about movie ticket booking system. And when I try to add a list off shows that have already existed into my Shows attribute in Movie class, it is always said that the Shows is null or the result is like this:
Show Date: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ASM_TicketBooking.Show]
This is class Movie.cs
internal class Movie
{
    private string title;
    private string description;
    private int durationMins;
    private string language;
    private DateTime releaseDate;
    private string genre;
    private List<Show> shows;

    public string Title
    { 
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; } 
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    public int DurationMins
    {
        get { return durationMins; }
        set { durationMins = value; }
    }

    public string Language
    {
        get { return language; }
        set { language = value; }   
    }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate
    {
        get { return releaseDate; }
        set { releaseDate = value; }
    }

    public string Genre
    {
        get { return genre; }
        set { genre = value; }
    }

    public List<Show> Shows 
    { 
        get { return shows; }   
        set { shows = value; }
    }
    public Movie()
    {
        shows = new List<Show>(_shows);
    }

    public Movie(string title, string description, int durationMins, string language, DateTime releaseDate, string genre, List<Show> shows)
    {
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        DurationMins = durationMins;
        Language = language;
        ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
        Genre = genre;
        Shows = shows;
    }

This is my add Show method to item into the Shows list
public List<Show> addShow()
{

    Show show1 = new Show(DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-11 05:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
        DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-11 06:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Show show2 = new Show(DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-12 07:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-12 08:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Show show3 = new Show(DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-13 09:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
        DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-13 10:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Show show4 = new Show(DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-14 11:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-14 12:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Show show5 = new Show(DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-15 17:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
        DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-15 18:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    Shows.Add(show1);
    Shows.Add(show2);
    Shows.Add(show3);
    Shows.Add(show4);
    Shows.Add(show5);

    Console.WriteLine("Add Shows successfully!");
    return Shows;
}

My method for add movies into movies list
public List<Movie> addMovie()
{
    
    Movie movie1 = new Movie("Romeo and Juliet: Afterlife", "Meadival Tragedy Romance", 
        300, "English", DateTime.ParseExact("2024-12-11 00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "Romance", movie.Shows);
    
    movies.Add(movie1);

    Console.WriteLine("Add movies successfully!");

    return movies;
}   

And my method for output the result to the console
public void getMovies()
{
    
    foreach (Movie movie in movies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Movie Title: {movie.Title}\n" +
            $"Description: {movie.Description}\n" +
            $"Duration: {movie.DurationMins}\n" +
            $"Language: {movie.Language}\n" +
            $"Genre: {movie.Genre}\n" +
            $"Release Date: {movie.ReleaseDate}\n" +
            $"Show Date: {movie.Shows}"
            );            
    }           
}

And the result is always like this: Result

Did you mean something like $"Show Date: {string.Join(",", movie.Shows)}" (does a show have a ToString suitable for describing itself? If no, you'll have to movie.Shows.Select...

Provide definition of Show class. Also why it has two dates? If you know duration of the movie, basically only show start date is required

This is the default "ToString()" behavior. Basically it is showing you the type of the Generic List object. If you want the details you need to loop through the list and write each item individually.
Here is an console app example:
var genericList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

Console.WriteLine(genericList.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(genericList.GetType().ToString());
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (var genericItem in genericList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(genericItem);
}

Output:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

one
two
three


But I want to attach the show list to every item in the movie list. Can I use the same method? Are there anymore solution to this problem?

My answer explains how to display the List contents. If implemented properly in your GetMovies() method it should print out each Show list that is referenced in each Movie object.
But you need to make sure that each Movie has a reference to a show list or you will get a null reference exception. If you are saying that every Movie object should reference the same Show list, then you may want to look at making the Show list a static variables.

Can you explain how I can reference the Show list in Movie object? I tried but it always throw null reference exception.
